# Kodi - no information available

Tags: kodi

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2. I've done all the system updates. No third party software was installed through original install.

I went to kodi.tv, previously xbmc and followed instructions for kodi install for Linux-Ubuntu. I followed the instructions until the kodi program was installed only. All instructions afterwards are convoluted. I ran kodi and it fired up like a charm. Then I followed standard instructions for installation of exodus. Once again everything loaded perfectly, however when I go to add-ons and start exodus it fires up no problem but when I click on anything such as popular shows or movies the left side of the screen says "no information available". The loading circle starts then stops with nothing happening afterwards. No choices of shows.

Comment: The additional repository is probably not compatible with Kodi's current version. That said, this isn't a Ubuntu question. You may want to ask for help at the Kodi community: http://forum.kodi.tv/

Comment: Failing Kodi add-ons are not uncommon. Many add-ons depend on websites over which the add-on developer have no control over. Any changes on such a webpage will potentially breaks the add-on. As @CelticWarrior says, trying to find recent information about the plugin in the kodi forum is your best bet to find a solution.